# What is the difference between semantic activation to lexical processing?

Tags: semantic-memory, priming

I am reading the review paper: [Levels of processing during non-conscious
perception: a critical review of visual masking](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2430002/)
and have encountered the terms: semantic activation and lexical processing.

Can anyone state what is the difference between the two?

I saw some definitions in the web but I look for something else.
I am looking for an example for an experiment which focuses on one methid and not the other.

Thanks!